# Bullet Physics ConvexDecomposition?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, physics, bullet-physics, mesh

I've looked at Bullet Physics **ConvexComposition** **Demo** and would like to implement that in my game but the code is so undescriptive and it's hard to understand what is going on. Would any of you people out there have the time to show how to use **ConvexDecomposition**?

Thank you very much!